# Matrix multiplication in a different representation

Tags: matrices

What I would like to do is figure out how to get the expression;

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{1} & x_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    y_{11} & y_{12} \\
    y_{21} & y_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    z_{1} \\ z_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
= x_{i}y_{ij}z_j$$ (Using Einstein summation) 
In to to the form
$$\rho (\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{1} & 0 \\
    0 & x_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    y_{11} & y_{12} \\
    y_{21} & y_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    z_{1} & 0 \\ 
    0 & z_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}) = x_{i}y_{ij}z_j$$
Where for $\mathcal{M} \in M_{2 \times 2}$ The set of $2 \times 2$ matrices over $\mathbb{F}$ we have the map, $\rho: \mathcal M \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$

I suppose that the padded 0's in the off diagonal for the matrices doesn't have to stay 0.

Thanks for your ideas,

Brian

Comment: Why the tag 'representation-theory'? I don't see any representation of groups here.

Comment: Hi Alex, I had put "representation-theory" as I am looking for an alternate way of representing matrices, I didn't know that the tag was only for group representations. I however removed it.

Comment: Hi Brian I was just curious and thought that you asked this question with representation theory of groups in your mind which you did not point out.

Comment: Wouldn't $\rho$ as the sum of the $4$ elements of the argument matrix do it?

Comment: Hi Simon, I don't quite follow - could you expound a little?  Thanks